# Rails join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I am pretty new in rails and honestly, I am struggling with queries even after multiple researchs.
Here is my simple schema:

[image]

So basically, a question has many options, an option belongs to a question and has many answer, and an answer belongs to an option and has many users.

I don't think it s necessary to post the models code since it is just like i mentioned above.

What i would like to do is given a question option, see if a particular user already checked it (so look in the answer table if there is a row matching a given id_option, user_id and user_type). So in my haml loop, when displaying the different question option, i'm calling a method of my question_option model just like this :

```rb
- question.question_option.all.each do |option|
    #{option.title}
    .check
        - if option.selected_by(current_actor)
            = check_box_tag(option.id, "checked",true, class: 'styled-checkbox')
        - else
            = check_box_tag(option.id, "checked",false, class: 'styled-checkbox')
```

and the method called :

```rb
def selected_by(answerer)
  answer_match =    
    ::Vacancies::QuestionOption
      .joins(:answers)
      .where(answerer_id: answerer.id, answerer_type:answerer.type )
  response = answer_match.find(self.id)
  return response
end
```

This method is located in my QuestionOption model and leads to no errors but it s not working ever.
Can you help me transform this query to make it work with ActiveRecord ? Thanks

Comment: "I don't think it s necessary to post the models code since it is just like I mentioned above.", please do it. Personally, it's easier to see the models and know how to replicate your scenario.

Comment: You are right i should have done it but since i resolved the problem i think this is not necessary anymore. Anyway, thanks for your interest to it. :D

Comment: You should post your solution below if you resolved it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. It checks if there are any answers by the user passed in the params on the question. I think this is what you intended to do as well-

```
def selected_by(answerer)
  answers =    
    Answer.where(answerer_id: answerer.id, answerer_type:answerer.type, id_option: self.id)

  answers.exists?
end
```

Comment: Might be more performant to use `exists?` at the end of the query instead of saving to variable and calling `present?`. also could just use `.where(answerer: answerer)`, Rails magic will compare both the type and id there. And then one final nag, since your expecting a boolean, it's convention to use a predicate method, ie `def selected_by?(answerer)`

Comment: You passed from loading a single database record to query all of them and do nothing with them, as stated by @Int'lManOfCodingMystery, the best improvement is to use `exists?` if you don't need to access any records' columns.